# Is it possible to connect directly CloudRun with Gitlab?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gitlab, google-cloud-run

I am trying to configure a continuously deployed revision from a source repository with CloudRun on Google Cloud. It is unclear to me how to set, as a source repository, GitLab instead of GitHub or BitBucket.

I also followed the [quickstart tutorial](https://console.cloud.google.com/?tutorial=run--quickstart-github-repo) but it still seems to be possible to configure only GitHub or BitBucket even if [there](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/quickstarts/deploy-continuously) define the procedure for git in general.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even when [Quickstart: Deploy to Cloud Run from a git repository](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/quickstarts/deploy-continuously#cloudrun_deploy_continuous_code-nodejs) states about git in general, you can only choose from one of the three supported repository providers:

- Github
- Bitbucket
- [Cloud Source Repositories](https://cloud.google.com/source-repositories/docs) (These are private git repositories hosted on Google Cloud)

However, there are tutorials online that describe workarounds in deploying to Cloud Run using a gitlab repository.

- [Deploying to Google Cloud Run with GitLab CI/CD: A Step-by-Step Guide](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/deploying-google-cloud-run-gitlab-cicd-step-by-step-guide-akinde)
- [Deploy to Cloud Run using GitLab CI](https://medium.com/google-cloud/deploy-to-cloud-run-using-gitlab-ci-e056685b8eeb)

Comment: Thank you. 
So at the moment is not possible to deploy an image directly from my GitLab container registry without paying for Artifact Registry or Container Registry because with both solutions I have to upload my images on Google.